# Why do I lose my .R file when adding Google play library on android?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I have an Android project in Eclipse. I'm trying to get Google Play (more specifically, Maps) working for the project.

I've downloaded Google Play services from the SDK Manager. Then I import google-play-services-lib via import (I've tried both copying the files to the activity and not). Then, I go to my project properties and add the library. The moment I hit apply, my R file disappears and I get errors in my code wherever I reference R. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: To my understand, you did nothing wrong. Just build the project again, so the R.java would be generated and all errors will be solved

Comment: I did. I rebuilt. I restarted Eclipse, my computer, no matter what I try, R.java won't generate.

Comment: Check the error message in Error Log. Your project wasn't built because there is some unsolved error

Comment: I could've sworn there wasn't anything besides "R cannot be resolved" 86 times over. This time, at the top is "Error executing aapt. Return code - 107374181"